# Recursive list building: permutations of all lengths

Tags: python, recursion

I've been having some trouble with recursion, especially with lists. I don't understand the process of 'building a list recursively' very well, since I don't really get where the lists are created. I have gotten this program to print out all the permutations of `len(string)`, but I would like to extend it so that it'll also give me the permutations of length 1 to `len(string) - 1`. Here is what I have got:

```
def subset(string):
    result = []

    if len(string) == 0:
        result.append(string)
        return result
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            shorterstring = string[ :i] + string[i+1: ]

            shortersets = subset(shorterstring)

            for s in shortersets:
                result.append(string[i] + s)
    return result
```

Which gives:

```
print(subset("rum"))
['rum', 'rmu', 'urm', 'umr', 'mru', 'mur']
```

I don't understand why that when I change `result.append(string[i] + s)`, to just `result.append(s)`, I get no output at all.

Comment: Note that the code in your `if` block will only ever return `['']`, i.e., a list containing an empty string.

Comment: Just a note. There's also [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function that does something similar. You might be interested in its source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `result.append(string[i] + s)` to `result.append(s)`, your code will only add permutations of length `len(string)` to `results` when `len(string) == 0`.

For your code to generate all permutations, the last for loop needs to be:

```
for s in shortersets:
    result.append(string[i] + s)
    result.append(s)
```

Note that when used with the original code, you will actually end up adding multiple instances of the same permutations to the final output. You could fix this by making `results` a `set` instead of a `list`, but you might want to try re-writing your code to avoid this inefficiency altogether.